# Difficulties with await open_account(ctx.author) for discord economy bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

The issue is on the line `await open_account(ctx.author)`. When I do the command in discord, it outputs the same response 4-5 times over but it functions as intended. Back in the prompt it highlighted the line I mentioned earlier. This also happens for any other client commands in this code. Any ideas how to fix it? Much appreciated.

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]


    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance")
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. However you can try to built in a `return` at the end of your code. If the bot sends out the command output multiple times you maybe have more than one instance running at once.

```py
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]


    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance")
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    return # Prevents the bot from sending more
```